# how to measure the height of textField

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

code:

```
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
var code by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var money by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

Column() {
    Row() {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
            value = code,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }),
            singleLine = true,

            label = { Text("Code") },
            onValueChange = { pscCode ->
                code = pscCode.filter { it.isDigit() }.take(16)
            })
        Button(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {…}
        )
        {
            Text("Save data")
        }
    }
    Row() {
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
            value = money,
            singleLine = true,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }),
            label = { Text("Money amount") },
            onValueChange = { moneyAmount ->
                money = moneyAmount
                    .trim()
                    .replace(",", ".")
                    .take(5)
            })

        Button(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {…}
        ) {
            Text("Clean data")
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to match the size of buttons to the size of textFields but I didn't find a way, I tried to measure the height of textBoxes (no results), is there a better (and working) way to fill those gaps?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**intrinsic measurements**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements):

```
   Row(Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
            TextField( /* your code */)
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                onClick = {}
            )
            {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
```

[image]

As explained in the doc:

> The Row composable's `minIntrinsicHeight` will be the maximum `minIntrinsicHeight` of its children. The `Button` element's `minIntrinsicHeight` is `0` as it doesn't occupy space if no constraints are given; the `TextField` `minIntrinsicHeight` will be that of the text given a specific width. Therefore, the `Row` element's height constraint will be the max `minIntrinsicHeight` of the `TextField`. `Button` will then expand its height to the height constraint given by the `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

Philip's answer also oughta do it.

Another workaround

```
var textFieldHeight: Dp

BoxWithConstraints(Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {

 TextField()
 textFieldHeight = maxHeight

}
```